# Highlighting text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to highlight the found phrases in text in a rails view. I have an instance variable that contains the text I want highlighted.

This works:

```
highlight(post.post_content, "World Series")
```

This does not (it doesn't highlight anything):

```
highlight(post.post_content, @query_str)
```

My instance variable is a string and when I output in in the view it does indeed contain the phrase "World Series". It doesn't work if @query_str contains a single word either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the phrase:

`<%= highlight(post.post_content, @query_str.split) %>`

Comment: Thanks @DashControl. I had actually tried that but it doesn't work either. As I said - even if my instance variable only contains one word (thus, not requiring .split) it won't work. Interestingly though, sometimes my instance variable contains "World Series" OR "MLB" in which case it will highlight the word "or" in my text.

Comment: DashControl - your comment actually helped me sort it out. My string actually contained double quotes, so the highlight method would never find a match. I stripped out the double quotes - and the word 'OR' which was also in the instance variable and the highlight routine works great. The highlight routine works correctly as I have it above - it was the contents of my variable that was the issue. @query_str = channel_search.query.gsub /["OR]/,''

Comment: ah, makes sense.  I'm glad it sparked your brain to figure it out :)